# jquery tabs border issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I've used jQuery tabs and can't override one thing.

```
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav {
    height: 2.35em;
    text-align: center;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0em;

}

#tabs .ui-widget-content { 
    border: none;
    background: none; 
    padding-left:13px;
}
#tabs .ui-widget-header { 
    border: none; 
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Sans-Serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
#tabs .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
    background:#b9c9fe; 
    border:1px solid #E0E0E0;
}
#tabs .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active {
    background:#e8edff none; 
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

The problem is that I can't get rid of the one, external border.

[image]

Anyone willing to help?

Thanks in advice.

HTML:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>TODO</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <p>TODO</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <p>TODO</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-4">
            <p>TODO</p>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-5">
            <p>TODO</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Added code with HTML code to show how it goes with CSS included.

Comment: Could we get a jsfiddle or some html code please?

Comment: The style is being added with this selector: `.ui-widget-content` your css selector above includes an ID, so it will be more specific than the one in jQuery UI.

Comment: Yea, can you show us some code on jsFiddle ?

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for answer, tried jsFiddle, but can't make it look like on my desktop. Like it lacks of jQuery, but you can see it here - http://jsfiddle.net/BYEY9/

Comment: sorry, not enough information to answer your question. Try to replicate whats on your desktop on the jsfiddle. jsfiddle allows you to add javascript, you have to select the jquery framework from the navigation on the left under 'Choose Framework'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This selector needs to be changed assuming #tabs is the element you called `.tabs()` on:

```
#tabs .ui-widget-content
```

to

```
#tabs.ui-widget-content
```

or

```
#tabs
```

Comment: if I make #tabs.ui-widget-content or #tabs it all messed up very much, buttons centered with no borders and previous structure. :)

Comment: It's not from the `padding-left:13px;` is it? It seems to work fine in the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BYEY9/

Comment: The centering of the tabs is happening somewhere else, the styles applied within `#tabs.ui-widget-content` have nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
.ui-widget-content{
    border: none !important;
}
```

it could also be

```
.ui-widget-header{
   border: none;
}
```

Comment: its the !important that will override the jquery-ui css

Comment: Right, but wouldn't using #tabs prior to .ui-widget-content make it more specific than jQuery UI's css?

Comment: Ah, i wonder if their both on the same element. That would explain it.

Comment: he didn't show his HTML , if he chose to go with the standard , and have a div with ID "tabs" - then #tabs .ui-widget-content {} would be the same , he could of very easily not used tabs , and this will work either way ,  if there are problems with other jquery-ui items that now don't have borders that you wanted borders , well then you have to go in there an be more specific

Comment: @Pawel - that didn't fix it ?